# Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cllocationmanager

I try to display the distance between a post creator and the current user within a cell.

My error now is

> **Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')**

in the following code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

        let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)

/*Here the error*/ let myBuddysLocation = CLLocation(latitude: job!.distance, longitude: job!.distance)

        let distance = myLocation.distance(from: myBuddysLocation) / 1000
        print(String(format: "The distance to my buddy is %.01fkm", distance))
    }
}
```

This is my JobClass:

```
class Job {

var distance: String?
let ref: DatabaseReference!

init(distance: String? = nil) {
    self.distance = distance
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").childByAutoId()
}

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){
    ref = snapshot.ref
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
        distance = value["distance"] as? String
    }
}

func save() {
    let newPostKey = ref.key
            let postDictionary = [
                "distance" : self.distance!
                ] as [String : Any]
            self.ref.setValue(postDictionary)
}
}
```

I hope someone knows how to solve it, if you wan't I can add more code if it helps // I'm new to coding

Comment: What makes you think that a `String` value (distance) can magically turn into a `Double` value?

Comment: What is the content of the string property `distance`, what exactly are you getting from your `DataSnapshot`?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal because distance should be Double value. Changing it to: `var distance: Double?` should correct it.
Or parse the value to Double `let myBuddysLocation = CLLocation(latitude: Double(distance)!, longitude: Double(distance)!)`

I recommend you to avoid using `!` because it could generate a fatal error if the string isn't a number, you can guard the value with guard or if let like this example:

```
if let latitude = Double(distance) {
    let myBuddysLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: latitude)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your function the only problem are there you passing the string value in place of double you need to change like this.

```
let myBuddysLocation = CLLocation(latitude: Double.init(job!.distance) ?? 0.0, longitude: Double.init(job!.distance) ?? 0.0)
```

You need to change your function like this

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

        let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)

        let myBuddysLocation = CLLocation(latitude: Double.init(job!.distance) ?? 0.0, longitude: Double.init(job!.distance) ?? 0.0) 

        let distance = myLocation.distance(from: myBuddysLocation) / 1000
        print(String(format: "The distance to my buddy is %.01fkm", distance))
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am not using single value for coordinate but i only solve his error. I use same code which is in question

Comment: Well the error in OP's question goes deeper than that, don't you think so?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson well i am not sure about this because he didnot give exactly which value fetch from database

Comment: Then why not ask OP to clarify that?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes that is not come in my mind thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191157/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: ok guys, I'm really really sorry for this late answer, I just got my macbook back from apple repair after 2 weeks... however, are you guys still up to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory: You are trying to set a `String?` instead of a `CLLocationDegrees`, but you can even use a `Double` type.

There are several ways to fix this:

1) You can change your class definition as it follows:

```
   class Job {

          // Change distance to Double and set a default value instead of optional
          var distance: Double = 0.0
          let ref: DatabaseReference!

          // Change the init
          init(distance: Double = 0.0) {
              self.distance = distance
              ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").childByAutoId()
          }

          //You have to change all your distance to Double
          init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){
              ref = snapshot.ref
              if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
                 // So change this cast
                  distance = value["distance"] as Double
              }
          }
         }
```

2) You can try a cast from **String?** to **Double**, but I don't recommend this.

Anyway, here it is how you can do it:

```
   if let dist = Double(job!.distance){
          let myBuddysLocation = CLLocation(latitude: dist, longitude: dist) -> Error Appears in this Line

           let distance = myLocation.distance(from: myBuddysLocation) / 1000
           print(String(format: "The distance to my buddy is %.01fkm", distance))
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean ? It doesn't seem to me he's trying to create a point on a map, but he's trying to retrieve distance between two locations.

Comment: I am talking about the second location, `myBuddysLocation`

Comment: The second location is taken from an object, we cannot know how he filled it but it is good for calculate distance from another location, aware of the possible results, of course. Anyway, I think this is off topic, He asked a solution for a compile error, not runtime or logic one.

Comment: Well maybe down voting was a little bit to harsh but since as you say your answer is not more than pointing out a simple compilation error maybe a comment to OP's question would have been enough.

Comment: I don't know what OP's question means, but If you can help me to understand, I will be happy to improve this answer with your advices.